# Does "packing" a pack of cigarettes before opening make them last longer?

Tags: smoking, cigarettes

To "pack" a packet of cigarettes is to whack them against a surface before opening the packet.

This is said to compress the tobacco.

Example: [WikiHow describes the process](http://www.wikihow.com/Pack-a-Pack-of-Cigarettes)

> Many times while smoking a cigarette, the cherry will fall out because the tobacco is too loose or the cigarette is flicked too hard. To ensure that everything is packed tightly, you can "pack" a pack of cigarettes.

Does this process improve the integrity or longevity of cigarettes?

Comment: I believe it is to improve the consistency of the smoke.  As opposed to the cigarette burning quickly and irregularly when loose, if packed more dense they would be more regular and burn slower